# Python/Numpy array with None as index

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning Python/Numpy at the moment but I quite don't understand what None means as index in arrays.
I want to compute the Euclidean distance between two 2-dimensional data sets x and y. The output should be should be a 2-dimensional array containing the Euclidean distances between

```
x[0] and y[0], x[0] and y[1], x[0] and y[2],..., 
x[1] and y[0], x[1] and y[1], x[1] and y[2], and so on.
```

The solution is: `np.sqrt(np.sum((x[:, None] - y[None])**2, -1)`

But I don't understand the difference between `x[:, None]` and `y[None]`? How are they reshaped? I just cannot image it in my head. May anyone help?

Comment: This is making  `x` as (n,1) shape, and `y` a (1,m) shape; which broadcast together to make a (n,m) difference.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use a quick example:

```
x = np.array([10, 20, 30])
y = np.array([1, 2])

x.shape
# (3,)

y.shape
# (3,)
```

Using `x[:, None]` adds an extra dimension:

```
x2 = x[:, None]

x2.shape
# (3, 1)

x2
# array([[10],
#        [20],
#        [30]])
```

Using `y[None]` preprends an extra dimension :

```
y2 = y[None]

y2.shape
# (1, 3)

y2
# array([[1, 2]])
```

Now when you perform an operation on both, the two arrays are broadcasted:

```
x[:, None] - y[None]

# array([[ 9,  8],
#        [19, 18],
#        [29, 28]])
```

This is equivalent to:

```
array([[10, 10],         array([[1, 2],
       [20, 20],    -           [1, 2],
       [30, 30]])               [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Interestingly, the creation of new axes with `None` indexing + broadcasting is pretty close to what a sparse [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) does: `xs, ys = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)`, `np.sqrt(np.sum((xs.T - ys.T)**2, -1))` (we need transposition) gives the same results as OP's solution. It uses up less memory too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try `.shape` and print it like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(size=10)

print(x.shape)
print(x[None].shape)
print(x[:,None].shape)
print(x[:,None,None].shape)
```

The output should be:

```
>>(10,)
>>(1, 10)
>>(10, 1)
>>(10, 1, 1)
```

So in general, the `None` adds a dimension at the corresponding index. Furthermore `print(x[None].shape)` yields the same as `print(x[None,:].shape)`.